# Unable to see clear picture Bootstrap LightBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

Searching for while on internet how to construct good Bootstrap Lightbox but something here is wrong. Watching this video www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-EZC46hOc8 and repeating after him but I got black screen where the picture is hovered www.dropbox.com/s/kw9fzoy8jjkxe49/pic.png?dl=0 . [Here is the original page](http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/) to Bootstrap Lightbox from where I started programming this.

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-lightbox.css" ref="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <h2>LightBox</h2>
                <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  area-hidden="true">
                    <div class="lightbox-content">
                        <img src="x.jpg" />
                        <div class="lightbox-caption">
                            <p>
                                This is lightbox
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox" class="span2 thumbnail">
                    <img src="x.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Posting an image of your problem doesn't really help. Make a jsfiddle or at least post a link.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is the use of the class hide. The following code:

```
<div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  area-hidden="true">
```

Needs to be changed to this according to the Github repo of the plugin:

```
<div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  area-hidden="true">
```

Also, the Github plugin page states it is updated to use bootstrap v3, not v2.3.2